# Javascript null error when using external script in a Rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

I am using a banner ad from an ad service provider, similar to google adsense.
Instruction from their site state clearly and simply that all we need to do is to copy the below code to the body of our webpage

```
<!-- Begin Hsoub Ads Ad Place code -->
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
  hsoub_adplace = [my account id];
  hsoub_adplace_size = '728x90';
//--></script>
<script src="http://ads2.hsoub.com/show.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- End Hsoub Ads Ad Place code -->
```

I have copied and pasted into my rails app, inside a body of a view file but the banner is not getting displayed and I can see javascript error (with browser inspect source)

> TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

**ps**: On old browsers the banner is getting displayed but never on recent versions of browsers.

**ps2**: The support of hsoub confirmed multiple times, there is no problem from their side (their code is fine and working on thousands of websites, and my account is active with no issues). And it must be a problem from my code.. I am thinking the way Rails handles javascript...
Can you please help me solve this error and get the banner displayed.

**ps3**: I am using rails `6.0.1` and turbolinks `5.2.0`

you can check the error/source code online at **https://tafqit.com/**

Comment: probably the turbolinks, could you able to display the banner when you refresh the page (F5)?

Comment: it never shows, tried refreshing..

Comment: Can you please add more details to the question, like a small view of your page, that will give us a clear understanding to help you out.

Comment: @SunilLulla I have mentioned the page itself. you can check at
t a f q i t . c o m

Comment: Do you have it working now? When I went to your site on a few different browsers and I see the ad working fine. Had to turn off my ad blocker to be able to see it

Comment: @bwalshy actually yes it is working now. the problem was caused by cloudflare.
When I disabled their Rocket Loader feature, banner started to appear..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is caused by Rocket Loader feature of CloudFlare cdn service

> Rocket Loader improves paint times for pages that include Javascript.
>   Visitors will have a better experience by seeing content load faster
>   and speed is also a factor in some search rankings.
>
> Rocket Loader improves paint times by asynchronously loading your
>   Javascripts, including third party scripts, so that they do not block
>   rendering the content of your pages.

I disabled it and banner is appearing now.

Answer (score 2):

I am going to guess that this is a script positioning issue. It looks like the script is possibly looking for elements that are not rendered yet, i.e. the document and document body is not ready. Move the scripts to the end of the page i.e. after the body tags and see if that helps. Otherwise please add the exact error and perhaps show a condensed view of your page and the scripts relative to the other elements.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello world</h1>
    </body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        hsoub_adplace = 12345;
        hsoub_adplace_size = '728x90';
    </script>
    <script src="http://ads2.hsoub.com/show.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</html>
```

I managed to get the `iframe` to load by moving the scripts

Scripts are (still) inside the `body` tags.

[image]

Comment: I have moved it out of body and still the same issue exists. the site is online at 
t a f q i t . c o m
would appreciate if you could take a look at the code / errors there.

Comment: I am not a front-end dev so there could be magic going on here that I am not aware of, but it still looks like those script tags are inside the `body`. You could probably also remove the `<!-- \\-->` tags from the first script element.